# Having nVidia OpenGL 32bit driver on a 64bit Debian system in multiarch

Tags: debian, nvidia, opengl, multiarch

I'm trying to install 32 bit nVidia drivers on my 64-bit system (to get wine working with OpenGL). So I tried:

```
root@grzes:/lib# aptitude install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 libxvmcnvidia1:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 libxvmc1:i386{ab} libxvmcnvidia1:i386
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 6,661 kB of archives. After unpacking 32.2 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libxvmc1 : Conflicts: libxvmc1:i386 but 2:1.0.7-1+deb7u2 is to be installed.
libxvmc1:i386 : Conflicts: libxvmc1 but 2:1.0.7-1+deb7u2 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
Remove the following packages: 
1) kaffeine 
2) kplayer 
3) libxine1-x 
4) libxine2-x 
5) libxvmc1 
6) libxvmcnvidia1 
7) mencoder 
8) mplayer 
9) mplayerthumbs 
10) nvidia-glx 
11) smplayer 
12) smplayer-themes 
13) smplayer-translations 
14) task-desktop 
15) task-gnome-desktop 
16) xine-ui 
17) xserver-xorg-video-all 
18) xserver-xorg-video-intel 
19) xserver-xorg-video-openchrome

Leave the following dependencies unresolved: 
20) digikam recommends mplayerthumbs 
21) libgl1-nvidia-glx recommends libxvmcnvidia1 
22) nvidia-kernel-dkms recommends nvidia-glx (>= 304.88)
23) youtube-dl recommends mplayer2 | mplayer 
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] q
Abandoning all efforts to resolve these dependencies.
Abort.
```

However, as you can see there is a conflict. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info on the internet is conflicting on this topic so here are 2 leads that I found. I do not have multiarch nor Debian but am still trying to assist anyway.

#### Area to investigate #1 - Wine

I think you want to install the 32-bit NVIDIA drivers inside of Wine. I found this thread, it's on a FreeBSD forum but is still applicable:

*excerpt: http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=26597*

> 3D acceleration is working with the 64bit nvidia driver provided that you install the 32bit version (same version number) into the chroot (tested with World of Warcraft, 8.0-RELEASE).

#### Area to investigate #2 - nvidia-glx

I found this thread on a crunchbang forum, but should still apply. Thread's titled: [Index» Help & Support (Testing/Unstable)» NVIDIA Drivers on x86_64 not installing x86 32bit OpenGL library](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=23524).

That thread suggested the installation of this package:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

Comment: The second option did the job, despite some warnings.

Comment: @Grzenio - Awesome! Glad that did the trick!